# Read, transform and write data within each partition in the DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Language - Scala

Spark version - 2.4

I am new to both Scala and Spark. (I am from python background, so the whole JVM ecosystem is quite new to me)

I want to write a spark program to parallelize following steps:

1. Read data from S3 in dataframe
2. Transform each row of this dataframe
3. Write the updated dataframe back to S3 at a new location

Let's say I have 3 items, A, B and C. For each of these items, I want to do the above 3 steps.

I want to do this in parallel for all these 3 items.

I tried creating an RDD with 3 partition, where each partition has one item, A, B and C, respectively.

Then I tried to use `mapPartition` method to write my logic for each partition (the 3 steps mentioned above).

I am getting `Task not serializable` errors. Although I understand the meaning of this error, I don't know how to solve it.

```scala
val items = Array[String]("A", "B", "C")
val rdd = sc.parallelize(items, 3)

rdd.mapPartitions(
partition => {
    val item = partition.next()

    val filePath = new ListBuffer[String]()
    filePath += s"$basePath/item=$item/*"

    val df = spark.read.format("parquet").option("basePath",s"$basePath").schema(schema).load(filePaths: _*)

    //Transform this dataframe
    val newDF = df.rdd.mapPartitions(partition => {partition.map(row =>{methodToTransformAndReturnRow(row)})})

    newDf.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(path)
})
```

My use case is, for each item, read the data from S3, transform it (I am adding new columns directly to each row for our use case), and write the final result, for each item, back to S3.

**Note** - I can read the whole data, repartition by items, transform and write it back, but repartition results in a shuffle, which I am trying to avoid, and the way I am trying is, reading data for each item in an executor itself, so that it can work on whatever data it gets, and there is no need for shuffle.

Comment: Spark is not really a framework you just start using straight out of the box. I would suggest you spend a little time with some tutorials to get a basic understanding of how to use Spark, because - as mentioned in the answer below - what you are doing is very much _not_ how to do things in Spark and providing full tutorials is a bit outside the scope of StackOverflow...

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt I get your point and I have quite a bit understanding of Spark as well. It would be appreciated if you can share your thoughts on how would you solve this problem. I know I can pull all the data, repartition by items, and then write the transformation and write the final result back. But the problem here is, repartition results in a shuffle, which I want to avoid. Hence my thought was that if I can read the partition itself within an executor then there is no need to shuffle.

Comment: I'm afraid your suggested solution here demonstrates a very poor understanding of Spark. Nesting dataframes is simple _not_ possible in Spark. Period. Also, if you worry about performance, why would you even consider an IO-intensive option?? IO is always the worst choice in terms of performance. Of course, you should only use shuffling steps, if you cannot achieve your goal with transformations alone, but Spark is built to handle shuffling efficiently.

Comment: Thanks @GlennieHellesSindholt for the clarification. I know my understanding of Spark is poor, that's why I am asking the solution here :) . Nesting is not possible then I think my thought itself is incorrect. I will move forward with the simple way then. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve using the approach that you have shown, but I feel that you might be going about it the *hard way*. Unless there is a good reason to do so, it is often best to let Spark (especially spark 2.0+) to let it do it's own thing. In this case, just process all three partitions using a single operation. Spark will usually manage your dataset quite well. It may also automatically introduce optimisations that you did not think of, or optimisations that it can not do if you try to control the process too much. Having said that, if it doesn't manage the process well, then you can start arguing with it by trying to take more control and do things more manually. At least that is my experience so far.

For example, I once had a complex series of transformations that added more logic to each step/DataFrame. If I forced spark to evaluate each intermediate one (e.g. run a count or a show on the intermediate dataframes) I would eventually get to a point where it couldn't evaluate one DataFrame (i.e. it couldn't do the count) because of insufficient resources. However, if I ignored that and added in more transformations, Spark was able to push some optimisations to earlier steps (from the later steps). This meant that the subsequent DataFrames (and importantly my final DataFrame) could be evaluated correctly. This final evaluation was possible *despite* the fact that the intermediate DataFrame, that on it's own could not be evaluated, was still in the overall process.

Consider the following. I use CSV, but it will work the same for parquet.

Here is my input:

```
data
├── tag=A
│   └── data.csv
├── tag=B
│   └── data.csv
└── tag=C
    └── data.csv
```

Here is an example of one of the data files (tag=A/data.csv)

```
id,name,amount
1,Fred,100
2,Jane,200
```

Here is a script that recognises the partitions within this structure (i.e. tag is one of the columns).

```scala
scala> val inDataDF = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("data")
inDataDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, name: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> inDataDF.show
+---+-------+------+---+
| id|   name|amount|tag|
+---+-------+------+---+
| 31|  Scott|  3100|  C|
| 32|Barnaby|  3200|  C|
| 20|   Bill|  2000|  B|
| 21|  Julia|  2100|  B|
|  1|   Fred|   100|  A|
|  2|   Jane|   200|  A|
+---+-------+------+---+


scala> inDataDF.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- amount: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- tag: string (nullable = true)


scala> inDataDF.write.partitionBy("tag").csv("outData")

scala>
```

Again I used csv rather than parquet so you can dispense with the options to read a header and infer the schema (parquet will do that automatically). But apart from that, it will work the same way.

The above produces the following directory structure:

```
outData/
├── _SUCCESS
├── tag=A
│   └── part-00002-9e13ec13-7c63-4cda-b5af-e2d69cb76278.c000.csv
├── tag=B
│   └── part-00001-9e13ec13-7c63-4cda-b5af-e2d69cb76278.c000.csv
└── tag=C
    └── part-00000-9e13ec13-7c63-4cda-b5af-e2d69cb76278.c000.csv
```

If you wanted to manipulate the contenst, by all means add whatever map operation, join, filter or whatever else you need between the read and write.

For example, add 500 to the amount:

```scala
scala> val outDataDF = inDataDF.withColumn("amount", $"amount" + 500)
outDataDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, name: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> outDataDF.show(false)
+---+-------+------+---+
|id |name   |amount|tag|
+---+-------+------+---+
|31 |Scott  |3600  |C  |
|32 |Barnaby|3700  |C  |
|20 |Bill   |2500  |B  |
|21 |Julia  |2600  |B  |
|1  |Fred   |600   |A  |
|2  |Jane   |700   |A  |
+---+-------+------+---+
```

Then simply write outDataDF instead of inDataDF.

Comment: The hard way is of course irrelevant. The approach was infeasible.

Comment: @GMc I get you are trying to do, and I have tried that myself. That's the easiest solution, read, repartition, transform, write back. But the problem here is, when I read the data for all the items and then I do a repartition, it results in a shuffle, which is very costly. To avoid this problem, my thought was, If I can read each partition from the executor itself, then there is no need to repartition and the shuffle goes away. In simple terms, every executor read some data, transforms it and writes it back, without any shuffle at all. Which is not possible in the simple solution you provided.

Comment: I'm not seeing the shuffle. I am seeing a FileScan, and 2 MapPartitions (one on read and one on write).

Comment: When I read the data for all the items and do a repartition by item in Spark, it will result in a shuffle, right ?

Comment: i guess the answer is it depends. in my case i am not seeing it. while a shuffle can result be a relatively expensive step, don't try to avoid it like the plague. A shuffle may be required to enable or optimise a subsequent step. Spark won't (shouldn't?) do a shuffle unless it thinks it has a good reason to do one. A join is an example of a good reason - in this case it should shuffle the smaller data set to align with the bigger one. in this case you are basically reading and writing the same dataset. So unless it is badly skewed, there shouldn't be a reason to shuffle.